# Paramiko ssh output stops at --more--

Tags: python-2.7, networking, ssh, paramiko

The output stops printing at --more-- any idea how to get the end of the output

```
 >>> import paramiko
 >>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 >>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 >>> conn=ssh.connect("ipaddress",username="user", password="pass")
 >>> channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
 >>> channel.send("en\n")
 3
 >>> channel.send("password\n")
 9 
 >>> channel.send("show security local-user-list\n")
 30
 >>> results = ''
 >>> channel.send("\n")
 1
 >>> results += channel.recv(5000)
 >>> print results

 bluecoat>en
 Password:
 bluecoat#show security local-user-list
 Default List: local_user_database
 Append users loaded from file to default list: false
 local_user_database
 Lockout parameters:
 Max failed attempts: 60
 Lockout duration:    3600
 Reset interval:      7200
 Users:
 Groups:

 admin_local
  Lockout parameters:
  Max failed attempts: 60
 Lockout duration:    3600
 Reset interval:      7200
 Users:
  <username>
    Hashed Password: 
    Enabled:         true
    Groups:

  <username>
    Hashed Password: 
    Enabled:         true
  **--More--**
```

As you can see above the output stops printing at --more-- any idea how to get the output to print till the end.

Comment: to further clarify the question, is there any function available in paramiko to disbale paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the height of the terminal in the paramiko connect method fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

It worked well with `time.sleep(0.001)`:

```
while connection.recv_ready():
    time.sleep(0.001)
    outputtostr += connection.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")
return outputtostr
```

Comment: How should a sleep statement affect the truncated output?

Comment: Please be more elaborate, provide an [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) for your answer.